# Which thread type to use, proper halt/abort?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating a simple program to control two motors and, for safety reasons, a light curtain. In the program, the user will hit "Run" and (on a new thread) the motors will move to various position if nothing enters the light curtain. If something does enter the light curtain, then an event is raised which must immediately stop all motion (i.e. stop the other thread).

What thread type should I use for this situation? I am vaguely familiar with `System.Threading.Thread` and have used `ThreadPool` for small, numeric calculation tasks.

Also, what is the appropriate way to safely stop the hardware (i.e. the thread) should the light curtain be broken? I've heard the `Abort()` method is not the way to go.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am using .NET 2.0.

Comment: I would do it in hardware - run a dedicated cable from the light-curtain controller that holds closed a power relay in the motor-control enclosure.  There should be a software signal as well so that operations can be restarted safely and without damage to work in progress or motors/gearboxes/tools etc from the break of motor control.

Comment: @MartinJames Actually, the motors are linear actuators so if they are moving a load at top speed and the power is cut they will continue to slide until slamming into the end. I would like to receive the signal, bring them to a fast, controlled near-stop, and then cut all power.

Comment: I bet the actuators would not slide far if the relay shorted them out or connected them to a low-impedance dummy load :)  Nevertheless, I take your point - a software-controlled stop may be safer overall.

Comment: A software solution, especially one involving a PC, will fail at a critical moment sooner or later. A hardware solution would be far safer. Ideally the motors would have some support for that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, hardware will be used to shut off power but there will be a very slight delay before doing so. During this delay, I would like to send a software command to 1.) Stop/Abort the thread that was moving motors (so it doesn't issue a new move command) and 2.) Send a signal to both motors to stop immediately in case they are in the middle of a move (i.e. "near-stop").

Comment: OK, that does make more sense now. How does the thread code look ? Is there a main loop inside?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well, I haven't started it yet; I want to know how/which type of thread to use. But the basic concept is that there is a predefined set of points to move to (x,y) in the set `points[n,2]` (`for` loop). Upon completion, the actuators should move to (0,0). So, I will need a thread to do this work (not on UI thread) and be able to "abort (i.e. stop motors and return)" if the light curtain is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Not only is `Thread.Abort()` not the safest thing for your code, it also does not look like a way to guarantee shutdown of the engines. Unless the thread-code is in some sort of loop pressing a dead-man switch all the time. In other words,

> to safely stop the hardware (i.e. the thread)

they don't seem to be the same thing.

Your motor-threads should co-operate, ie continuously poll a cancel-flag. That holds for all solutions (Thread, TPL).

Comment: This is the best answer. Cancellation _must_ be cooperative for multiple reasons.